# Executing Node Forever module in Crontab fails

Tags: module, cron, send, forever

In root user crontab I added the below job:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/forever start /root/MyCode/server.js >> /root/ou1.log 2>&1
```

I am getting the below error:

```
info:    Forever processing file: /root/MyCode/server.js

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:419
```

monitor.send(JSON.stringify(options));
          ^
    TypeError: Object # has no method 'send'
    at Object.startDaemon (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:419:11)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:258:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:145:5
    at Object.oncomplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:358:11)

But if I manually run the forever command in terminal, its working..

Forever "version": "0.11.1"
node version: v0.10.17

Comment: It seems like some problem with the installation. In the above example am using a vagrant box. I installed forever in fresh vagrant box, and it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like some problem with the installation. In the above example am using a vagrant box. I installed forever in fresh vagrant box, and it worked..